# How to format long echo expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, coding-style

I'm writing my function in PHP for listing post categories (just look at code style, not logic):

```
function list_categories() {
    // $html = '';

    echo '<div class="post-categories post-items__categories">';
    echo '<span class="post-categories__title">Categories:</span>';

    echo '<ul class="post-categories__list">';
    echo '<li class="post-categories__item"><a class="post-categories__link">All categories</a></li>';

    $categories = get_categories([
        'taxonomy'     => 'category',
        'type'         => 'post',
        'orderby'      => 'name',
        'order'        => 'DESC',
        'hierarchical' => false,
    ]);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $cat_class = ($category->term_id == get_queried_object_id()) ? 'active' : '';

        echo '<li class="post-categories__item">
                  <a class="post-categories__link" href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id).'">'.
                     $category->name.
                 '</a>
              </li>';
    }

    echo '</ul></div>';
}
```

And I want my tag echoing expressions to be more readable, not just in one line like here:

```
echo '<li class="post-categories__item"><a class="post-categories__link">All categories</a></li>';
```

I'm using new lines in foreach loop, but it's still ugly.
I found out about heredoc syntax, but I can't call functions inside it.
How do you write this kind of things? I really don't want to write all in one line

Comment: Seems like heredoc is the best solution, but we need to declare extra variables for storing function results. Anyway I want to know your approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to echo HTML why not break out of PHP, then back into it so

```
function list_categories() {
    // $html = '';

    echo '<div class="post-categories post-items__categories">';
    echo '<span class="post-categories__title">Categories:</span>';

    echo '<ul class="post-categories__list">';
    echo '<li class="post-categories__item"><a class="post-categories__link">All categories</a></li>';

    $categories = get_categories([....
```

becomes...

```
        function list_categories() {
            // $html = ''; 
    
    //break out of php
    ?> 
        
            <div class="post-categories post-items__categories">
            <span class="post-categories__title">Categories:</span>
        
           <ul class="post-categories__list">
            <li class="post-categories__item"><a class="post-categories__link">All categories</a></li>
        
   <!--carry on with php-->
    <?php 
        
            $categories = get_categories([....
```

And if you need to call a variable in the middle of html code you can like so..

```
<?php $demo = "hello"; ?>
<span><?php echo $demo; ?> World</span>
```

HTML in a variable...

```
<?php $html = ' ?>
<!--HTML HERE-->
<?php '; ?>
```

Comment: Oh, and HTML code that is out of php tag will just be echoed? I didn't know that, thank you. What if I don't want to echo, but to just store HTML in my $html variable (or concatenate) with it using $html .=?

Comment: @leonscander have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Great. I got it. Thank you!